# how to pick the scribd id from embed_url and url using javascript regualr expression

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my embed url

```
<a title="View Skittles Brand Book on Scribd" **href="http://www.scribd.com/doc/32214928/Skittles-Brand-Book"** style="margin: 12px auto 6px auto; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; -x-system-font: none; display: block; text-decoration: underline;">Skittles Brand Book</a><iframe class="scribd_iframe_embed" src="http://www.scribd.com/embeds/32214928/content?start_page=1&view_mode=list&access_key=key-10htmr9272mhv32jzem8" data-auto-height="true" data-aspect-ratio="1.1858407079646" scrolling="no" id="doc_15097" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe><script type="text/javascript">(function() { var scribd = document.createElement("script"); scribd.type = "text/javascript"; scribd.async = true; scribd.src = "http://www.scribd.com/javascripts/embed_code/inject.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(scribd, s); })();</script>
```

How to pick id from this embed code?

Comment: Please format your code it's unreadable.

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript solution:

```
var result = inputString.match(/id="([^"]*)/);
alert(result[1]);
```

This searches for the string `id="` and then match everything that is not a `"`, this part is put into a capturing group becasue of the brackets around it, you find this then in `result[1]`.

be careful if there are more than one `id="` in your string.

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ324/3/) (I removed the script part from the end of the example string)

Comment: Thanks for the info, also i don't have idea w.r.t JS can you solve this question [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/tQ324/1/)?

Comment: @Abhishek Simon, I am no javascript expert, but there is another script included at the end of the example string. for my example I took out the script part at the end of the string `<script ... </script>'` then it worked. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ324/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
(?<=id=")[a-z\_0-9]+
```

It will give you the value of `id` from your embedded code

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but sadly javascript does not support lookbehinds [regular-expressions.info/javascript.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)